# Android : Get the token using GoogleAuthUtils. Invalid Client ID

Tags: android, access-token, google-authentication

I am trying to get authenticated token from GoogleAuthUtils. Keep having Invalid Client ID message like this.

> GLS error: INVALID_CLIENT_ID myEmailAddress audience:server:client_id:**NUM**.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://picasaweb.google.com/data

The NUM = xxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com where I used xxxxxxx part. I even tried using the y parts or both but none works. Am I missing something here?

```
 String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(PicassaFragment.this.getActivity(),
                        Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(client),
                        scope
                );
```

This is the code i received the error message.